# call c function from a .c file with a main function

Tags: c

I have two .c files that both have mains.  One of the files has a function that I would like to use in the other main.  Is it possible to reference this other function without copying and pasting it into the other .c file?

Comment: Where are the files?

Comment: They are in the same directory.

Comment: Please explain the way you build them. And post their contents if possible, you can't have two `main()` funcitons.

Comment: I have wrote a .c file that I plan to compile and execute to perform one task.  I have another .c file that I plan compile and execute a completely separate task.  The second  .c file needs to use a function that is defined in the first .c file.  I could just copy and past the function into the second .c file, but I was wondering if there was a way to "link" the particular function I want to use.

Comment: You'll get duplicate symbol error if you link normally.

Comment: What compiler, platform, build tool -- are you using?

Comment: @TwilightSun yes I know.  The best solution that I have is to just copy and paste the code.  I was wondering if there might be something slicker though.

Comment: It's the worse solution by far. You should never duplicate the code, if there is a bug in the common code then ... you see the problem don't you?

Comment: You may compile the other .c file to a library, static or dynamic should both work. But I think it's anti-pattern, you'd better just put that common function in a separate file.

Comment: Please check my answer, does it help you understand how to do it?

Comment: I've commented on your answer giving a much broader view of my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to copy and paste, suppose you have this

**program-one.c**
*First program*.

```
#include "common.h" /* This should be implemented */

int main(void)
{
    do_program_one_stuff();
    common_function();
    return 0;
}
```

**program-two.c**
*Second program*.

```
#include "common.h" /* This should be implemented */

int main(void)
{
    do_program_two_stuff();
    common_function();
    return 0;
}
```

You need a third *.c* file and a *.h* file, like this

**common.c**
*Common Functions Implementation*.

```
void common_function()
{
    /* Do it here */
}
```

**common.h**
*Common Functions Header*.

```
void common_function();
```

You now can compile a single binary for each program consisting of two files, the program specific *.c* file and *common.c*.

The right way to do it is to have a *Makefile* and generate object code first, and then link the object files togeather, thus compiling each file only once.

**Makefile**
*This is a [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) Makefile using [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as the compiler.*

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -O0 # enable debug symbols and warnings
LDFLAGS = # linker flags here ...
OBJ     = common.o program-one.o program-two.o

all:
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) common.o program-one.o -o program-one
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) common.o program-two.o -o program-two

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    @rm -fv *.o program-one program-two
```

**EDIT**: *in response to your comment I would suggest the following*

```c
#define main ignore /* Or whatever name you want */
#include "the-student-implementation.c"
#undef main

int main(void)
{
    /* This would be your `main()' */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I should be more clear.  Your answer is correct, but it doesn't solve what I would like to do.  I'm trying to write a grading script for student hw submissions that have both the functions I need to check for correctness and a main method in the same file.  A common .h file was provided to each student so that they could do exactly as you have done above (I would need to just write the test main then).  However, many students did not create a seperate .c file for the commonFunction(); placing in the came .c file as their main.  I would like to be able to call this function in my main

Comment: This way, I could create a simple bash script that will go through and automatically check each submission.  However, to the best of my knowledge I can't do this because of the duplicate mains.

Comment: What about `#define main ignore #include "c-file.c" #undef main`? I think this should let you achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.  Could you give an example?

Comment: I just did, the idea is to make the preprocessor replace the `main()` with something else when you include the students *.c* file, and then undef it to let you write your `main()`.

Comment: It should be mentioned that having two `main()` is unorthodox and generally doesn't make sense. If you need several executables, build several executables. If you need one executable leading to several processes, create processes in run-time by calling an OS API. If you need two executables communicating with each other, there is [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) such as _pipes_.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is what iharob suggested, but if for some reason that isn't possible, you could surround the main() in the file containing the common function with #ifdef USE_MAIN, then only define the USE_MAIN identifier in the command to build that project.  When you build the other project that doesn't have USE_MAIN defined, the preprocessor will cause the second main() to be skipped, so the compiler won't be confused.

But unless this is really needed, I highly recommend splitting this into three files: main1.c, main2.c, and common.c/common.h